# Cannot reload or start AppArmor in Docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apparmor

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt-get install -y python-software-properties

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN apt-get install -y apparmor-profiles
RUN apt-get install -y apparmor-utils

ADD server.js /folder1/
ADD usr.bin.nodejs /etc/apparmor.d/

RUN service apparmor reload

CMD node /folder1/server.js
```

Here is `usr.bin.nodejs`:

```
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/bin/nodejs {
  #include <abstractions/base>

  /usr/bin/nodejs mr,
  /folder1/server.js r,
  /folder1/repo/** ralkmix,
  network,

}
```

I run `sudo docker build -t scadge/test-one .` to build this image. On `Step 7 : RUN apt-get install -y apparmor-profiles` I get red messages `invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start` and `invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of reload`. Also on `Step 11 : RUN service apparmor reload` I get the following:

```
 * Reloading AppArmor profiles
 * Mounting securityfs on /sys/kernel/security...
mount: permission denied
    ...fail!
    ...fail!
```

..and sure thing apparmor profiles are not working. So how do I make AppArmor work in Docker? I would also like to admit that all this stuff works fine on my desktop Ubuntu 14.04, downloaded from official site.

Answer (score 4):

First a disclaimer. You don't want to do this!

Because **reloading AppArmor profiles in the container reloads them in the host**!

This is because the Docker container shares the running Linux kernel with the host.

The container itself is already confined using the `/etc/apparmor.d/docker` profile, BTW.

---

Now, if you *really sure* you want to load the host AppArmor profiles from the container...

The problem is kind of obvious, AppArmor can't mount the securityfs.

You can enable the mount by using the `--privileged` option.

[You can also enable it](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration) with the `SYS_ADMIN` [capability](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html):

```
docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN debian:jessie sh -c 'mount -t securityfs none /mnt && echo Done!'
```

If you use the `SYS_ADMIN` option then you'd have to edit the `/etc/apparmor.d/docker` profile *on the host* and comment out all the `deny` lines involving the `/sys/kernel` branch.

Again, this is most probably not something you want to do.

Comment: Why does the container uses the host apparmor? Isn't that violating the entire encapsulation of a container?

Comment: @HolgerBarlt On one hand, encapsulation is never perfect, there might be exploitable vulnerabilities in a hardware emulator for instance. On another hand, the attack surface in Docker might be indeed larger

Comment: cf. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/169642/what-makes-docker-more-secure-than-vms-or-bare-metal